# Como iniciar um classe no mesmo arquivo .java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, windows

Eu sou novo nessa parte de compilação pra APP Android, eu gostaria de saber como iniciar uma classe q está no mesmo arquivo java, por exemplo: meu 'MainActivity', já declarado o botão que deveria iniciar a classe "UDP_Client", mas toda vez q aperto esse botão ele dá erro, alg pode me ajudar??

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String MESSAGE_RECEIVED = "";
public String Payload = "2459247B0";
public String IP_Address = "192.168.2.255";
public String FeedbackUDP;
public String eltin;

public int port = 4212;

public boolean Server_Act = true;
public boolean turnCheck = false;

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main););
    Switch turn = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    final TextView ip = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final TextView payload = findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    turnCheck = turn.isChecked();

    turn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(turnCheck = true){
                Payload = "2459247B1";
                payload.setText(Payload);
                ip.setText(eltin);
            }else{
                Payload = "2459247B0";
                payload.setText(Payload);
                ip.setText(eltin);
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UDP_Client.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            UDP_Client client = new UDP_Client();
            try {
                client.NachrichtSenden();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

E a classe UDP_Client

```
class UDP_Client extends IOException {

MainActivity dir = new MainActivity();
private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void NachrichtSenden() throws UnknownHostException {
    asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        byte[] ip = InetAddress.getByName(dir.IP_Address).getAddress();
        InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try
            {
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(4212,IP);
                DatagramPacket packet;
                packet = new DatagramPacket(dir.Payload.getBytes(), dir.Payload.length(), IP, dir.port);
                socket.setBroadcast(true);
                socket.send(packet);
                dir.eltin = IP.getHostAddress();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                dir.eltin = "ERROR!";
                dir.Payload = "ERROR!";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

}

E o erro...

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.automatizze/com.example.automatizze.UDP_Client}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class is not accessible from java.lang.Class

Alg faz alg ideia do q seja?

Comment: quando você chama  `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UDP_Client.class);` `startActivity(intent);` o método recebe como parâmetro uma classe que extenda de AppCompat... Mas no seu caso você tá chamando uma classe de asynctask e não uma activity, por isso o erro. Removendo essa parte que coloquei, talvez seja possível anular o erro. Mas ainda assim acredito que dará erro nessa classe de asynctask, tá meio confuso.

Comment: Ele não deu erro, porém não inicializou o UDP_Client :/ 
E agr?

Comment: Mudei um pouco o código, ao invés de inciar a class com `UDP_Client client = new UDP_Client();
            try {
                client.NachrichtSenden();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }`
To iniciando com:
`UDP_Client client = new UDP_Client();
                client.asyncTask.execute();`

Comment: Se essa asynctask está no mesmo arquivo java da MainActivity, retira todo instância da MainActivity na classe UDP_Client. Como você já declarou as variáveis na classe principal, você não precisa criar uma instância pra manipular ela. Ou seja ao invés de usar: dir.eltin, apenas use eltin. Se mesmo assim não funcionar, tenta debugar linha/por linha e verifique os valores retornados.